# Unable to NPM install/start on an angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, gitlab

I  have been having this issue for  many weeks now. I am unable to install/start this project after cloning from the repository.

**When I use "npm start"**

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from ...
```

**When I use "npm i"**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   jasmine-core@"^3.3" from karma-jasmine@2.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/karma-jasmine
npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine@"~2.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer karma-jasmine@">=1.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!       dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.5" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: jasmine-core@4.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   peer jasmine-core@">=3.5" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.4" from the root project
```

**When I use "npm i --legacy-peer-deps"**

```
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Node-gyp failed to build your package.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update npm and/or node-gyp and if it does not help file an issue with the package author.
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

**What I have done**

1. I have reinstall node
2. Delete package-lock.json/package.json and then "npm i"
3. Reclone the git repostory
4. Reinstall Visual Studio Code
5. Install Visual Studio Installer
6. Npm update

Comment: try npm i --force

Comment: same error as the "npm i --legacy-peer-dep"

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in past days when trying to npm install using node with too new version of npm (angualar 14, node 14.16/16.13/18.7, npm 8.15). Try to downgrade npm version using

```
npm install -g npm@version
```

I used npm@8.5.0 and it worked

Comment: Hi, Im still having the same issue after using the command above

Comment: could you provide more informations about environment (node and npm version, angular version) and your package.json?